# How to stop wicket-ajax-indicator beside the next button of DynamicWizardStep from disappearing?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, wicket

I am new to wicket. I am trying to modify a codebase which is using wicket.
There is a class which extends DynamicWizardStep.

While executing, when the next button is clicked for a particular step, a progress indicator (wicket-ajax-indicator) appears beside next button and "applyState()" method of that step gets executed. However, if applyState() takes more than a minute to execute, the progress indicator disappears.

Also, in this case, the wizard does not proceed to the next step unless page is refreshed manually.

Is there a way to make the indicator wait for apply state to get executed? or atleast a way to increase the timeout?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Also, in this case, the wizard does not proceed to the next step unless page is refreshed manually.

Please check whether your Ajax request runs into a 504 Gateway Timeout. Speed up your execution, increase the timeout or register a failure handler:

```
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/ajax.html#ajax_6
```

Comment: How to increase the timeout?

Comment: The timeout is configured somewhere between your browser and your web server, e.g. a load balancer or gateway.